# UPDATE json array using aggregrate function

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

Working with Postgres 9.3, Python 2.7, psycopg2.
I have a table called `SomeTable` with a json field `some_json_array` and `row_id` key.

`some_json_array` looks something like this:

```
"[{'key': 'value_one'}, {'key': 'value_two'}, etc]"
```

I also have a function in which I'm trying to add some elements to the json array of `SomeTable` corresponding to the given `row_id`.

My code is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_elements (insertion_id smallint, new_elements_json json)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE SomeTable
    SET some_json_array = (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(some_json_array) || array_agg(new_elements_json)))
    WHERE row_id = insertion_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot use aggregate function in UPDATE
```

which I believe is complaining about `array_agg()`.

How would I modify this function to make it work? I can stick the `WHERE` clause into the `SELECT` statement if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate functions cannot be used like plain functions, only in an aggregate context.

Since Postgres cannot manipulate JSON arrays directly (it's just a valid [`json`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-json.html) *value* to Postgres, not an array) you have to ...

- either cast the `json` value to `text`, concatenate the new element, generating valid JSON syntax and transform back,
- or transform to a Postgres array of `json`: `json[]`, append the new element and transform this Postgres array back to a `json` value.
  `array_to_json()` is smart enough to not encode the `json` elements of the Postgres array another time.

The first approach is much more error prone. You would have to build valid JSON by hand. Here is an implementation of the second variant:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_elements (_id int2, _elem json)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
    UPDATE SomeTable s
    SET    some_json_array = array_to_json(ARRAY(
              SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(s.some_json_array)
              UNION  ALL SELECT _elem
              ))
    WHERE  s.row_id = _id;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The function wrapper is mostly irrelevant to the problem. Could just be a plain SQL statement.

Related:

- [How to turn json array into postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)

Comment: So it turns out that the resulting json from the `add_elements()` function doesn't actually become a true json object because I can no longer access the values using `->>` without getting this error `Cannot extract field from a non-object`. Was this an expected side effect?

Comment: I got it! So the current code returns a an array within an array, so all I did was replace `UNION ALL SELECT _elem` with `UNION ALL SELECT json_array_elements(_elem)` and got the original json format!

Comment: My function expects a single *JSON element*, not  a *JSON array*. Hence the parameter name `_elem` - guess I missed the intention behind your parameter name `new_elements_json`. Your fix is the way to go.