# Cannot extract field from a non-object, Postgres json array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I have a table called `Stores` which has a key called `store_id` and a table called `Sales` which contains a `store_id` reference and a json field called `sales_json`.

`sales_json` looks something like this:

```
[{'start_date': '2-20-15', 'end_date': '2-21-15', 'start_time': '11:00 AM', 
  'end_time': '11:00 PM', 'discount_percentage': 20}, etc]
```

I have a plpgsql function in which I'm trying to determine if a store is currently having a sale and store a boolean called `having_sale` in the result table depending on whether this is true or not.

My SELECT statement looks like this:

```
SELECT Stores.store_id,
       CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM (SELECT *
                        FROM json_array_elements(sales_json) AS sale
                        WHERE (now()::date BETWEEN (sale->>'start_date')::date AND
                                                   (sale->>'end_date')::date) AND
                              (now()::time BETWEEN (sale->>'start_time')::time AND
                                                   (sale->>'end_time')::time)
                       ) AS current_sales) > 0
                  THEN TRUE
            ELSE FALSE
       END) AS having_sale
FROM Stores INNER JOIN Sales
ON Stores.store_id = Sales.store_id;
```

The code looks correct to me but I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.DataError: cannot extract field from a non-object
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: It is possible that some of the elements within one or more of the sales_json arrays are not actually objects? Ie. could you have any null values in there?

Comment: Hi, I'm testing using the `sales_json` value from above, and it does not contain any null values.

Comment: Well, there is an extra bracket in your query above but other than that it works fine for me using the test data you have described above - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/59fd7/2 - so I think it has something to do with your input data. The only way I could get that error message was by inserting an empty array into one of the sales_json entries, eg: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e70fa/1

Comment: That's strange, I'm using the same exact input as the one that works for you, but still no dice :\

Comment: Your sqlfiddle code works for me but my code that uses similar but more complex tables and through psycopg doesn't work for some reason. It may have to do with the typecasting on the json input as it gets called into my function from python.

Comment: I suggest you test your queries and examine the data content in the database using psql, ie. bypassing python/pyscopg, the problem may become more apparent then.

Comment: I found out the problem. I wasn't inserting the sales_json value into the table but actually updating it and setting it to a new json array I constructed after concatenation. This left an unintended side effect as I'm not actually left with a json anymore but a normal array, hence being unable to access values from it using keys. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thats great. In order to help others, please post a full answer to your own question describing how you overcame it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was caused by a function I wrote that appends a json array to `sales_json`. I fixed it and now it looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_sales (insertion_id smallint, new_sales_json json)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE Sales
    SET sales_json = array_to_json(ARRAY(SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(sales_json)
                                         UNION ALL SELECT json_array_elements(new_sales_json)))
    WHERE store_id = insertion_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I was previously missing the `json_array_elements()` call on new_sales_json, which is why I was getting an array within an array and thus the `cannot extract field from a non-object` error.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the [mix-up of element and array input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621738/update-json-array-using-aggregrate-function/28622080#28622080) that you sorted out yourself, you can also largely simplify your `SELECT` statement:

```sql
SELECT store_id
     , EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM   json_array_elements(s.sales_json) sale
          WHERE  now() BETWEEN (sale->>'start_date')::date + (sale->>'start_time')::time
                       AND     (sale->>'end_date')::date  + (sale->>'end_time')::time
          ) AS having_sale
FROM   Stores st
JOIN   Sales  s USING (store_id);
```

Shorter and faster.
Adding time and date results in a `timestamp [without time zone]`. It might be a good idea to store timestamp data instead of date and time to begin with.

Except, if your times are meant as *daily schedules*, not as absolute bounds in combination with the dates. Then you must keep your original expressions.

Finally, `BETWEEN` includes both bounds, while you would typically *include* the lower bound and *exclude* the upper:

```sql
WHERE  now() >= (sale->>'start_date')::date + (sale->>'start_time')::time
AND    now() <  (sale->>'end_date')::date   + (sale->>'end_time')::time
```

And be aware that your date and time are interpreted according to the current setting of the time zone.

Comment: Given my `SELECT` statement and `sales_json` from my original post, it turns out that I get `false` as the result when today is `2-20-15` and the time is `11:01 PM`, when I should actually be getting `true`. Though your solution doesn't address the original problem which I figured out myself, it does fix this issue. The optimization is just as valuable. Thanks!

Comment: Note that there's an extra parenthesis here: `(sale->>'end_date')::date)`

Comment: and here: `) AS having_sale`